Identify old color movie where a storm destroys a coastal house and guy in it who refuses to leave
A long time ago (30 or 40 years) on U.S. television, I saw a show, probably a movie but possibly a tv show, which took place in some kind of coldish climate, I think it was an island.  I am guessing it was a British island but unsure. Maybe New England or Canada. Definitely not tropical. Could have just been coastline and not an island.  I think people were wearing coats and sweaters and such.
I seem to recall that there was a main character or a couple, who were facing a giant storm that was coming, and they took shelter inland.  They tried to convince an old guy, a fisherman I think, who lived in his house close to the water, to flee, but he refused.
After the storm they come back to the location of his house, which I think was a beach, and where his house used to be was just a few timbers/foundation left, with the waves washing over it, no sign of him or the house, the implication was that the storm and the sea took him and his house in the dark of night.
Any ideas what this could be?  Would have to be something from the 1980s or before.  I don't remember anything else.  Just remember that scene of them looking at the wreckage, and imagining what it must have been like in the dark of the night and the storm when it washed his house away with him in it, made an impression I have never forgotten.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Soufri%C3%A8re_(film)
